# Custom function in My Custom Functions returning 403

Tags: functions

In My Custom Functions plugin I have

```
function dropin_location() {
   if (is_page ('7')) {     
       echo '<script>';
       echo "alert('got here')";
       echo '</script>'; 
   }
}
add_action('init', 'dropin_location');
```

On saving I get 403 error 'Access to this resource on the server is denied!'
What am I doing wrong please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_head`. This will insert the script in the head.

```
function dropin_location() {
    if ( is_page( 7 ) ) {
        ?>
        <script>alert('got here')</script>'
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'dropin_location');
```

However, there are other ways to add scripts. You can have it as a script file in your theme and enqueue it so that WordPress "knows" about it. This way it can have dependencies, load at the correct time, etc. [Here is an explanation](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/).

So if you have `my-killer-script.js` in your theme, you can do the following:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
        'some-script-handle', // some name to give it
        get_theme_file_uri( '/path/to/my-killer-script.js' ), // file path to script
        array( 'some-dependency-handle' ), // does this script need any dependencies? If so, add their handles, or leave the array empty.
        false, // do you need a version?
        true // load in footer? true/false
    );
```

[Read the WP docs on wp_enqueue_script here.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Comment: Many thanks. I have gone the wp_enqueue_script route and it works correctly.

Comment: @user2005143 good to hear it's working. If you have a chance, please accept the answer.

Comment: Happy to accept the answer. What do i specifically have  to do to achieve that?

Comment: @user2005143 there should be a check mark at the top, to the left of this answer. Click on that.